# necessary condition for $\mathbb{R}^2$ vectors to sum up to zero

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, determinant

A necessary (not sufficient) condition for two vectors $u,v$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to sum up to zero is that they have to be linearly dependent, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\det\left(u,v\right) = 0
\end{equation}
Is there a similar necessary condition for $n$ vectors $u_1,u_2\dots u_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

I believe the following could be a candidate but it's rather ugly and does not have nice symmetries:
\begin{equation}
\det\left(u_1,u_2\right) +\det\left(u_1,u_3\right) + \cdots + \det\left(u_1,u_n\right) = 0
\end{equation}
Any better solutions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix The vanishing of this determinant is a necessary and sufficient condition for the vectors to be linearly dependent. To sum to zero is much more than that, however.

Comment: Isn't what you wrote equivalent to $\det(u_1,u_2+u_3+ \cdots + u_n) = 0$?

Comment: Consider $u_1 = (1,0)$, $u_2 = (1,1)$, and $u_3 = (1,-1)$. The sum of $\det\left(u_1,u_2\right) +\det\left(u_1,u_3\right) = 0$ but the vectors don't add up to 0

Comment: @CulDeVu that's why he's asking for a *necessary* condition, not a sufficient one

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro could you turn the comment into an answer? It might just be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix

The vanishing of the determinant
$$\tag{1}
\det(u_i\cdot u_j)_{1\le i,j\le n}
$$
is a necessary and sufficient condition for the vectors to be linearly dependent with real scalars. This means that there exist $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\ldots, \lambda_n\in \mathbb R$ such that $\lambda_j\ne 0$ for at least one value of $j\in\{1, 2\ldots n\}$ and 
$$
\lambda_1 u_1+\lambda_2 u_2+\ldots+ \lambda_n u_n=0.
$$

In particular the vanishing of (1) is a necessary condition for 
$u_1+u_2+\ldots + u_n=0$. This condition is not sufficient, however.

Answer (score 0):

As @David K pointed out in the comments, note that

$$ \sum_{i=2}^n \det(u_1, u_i) = \det(u_1, \sum_{i=2}^n u_i) $$

Now assuming $0 = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i = 1 \cdot (u_1) + 1 \cdot (\sum_{i=2}^n u_i)$ it's clear that $\det(u_1, \sum_{i=2}^n u_i) = 0$